# Table structures for large volume data imports

Tags: mysql

I have a general question about the best way to set up my tables to deal with large volume data that I import on a daily basis.
I will import 10 csv files containing 1000's records each day so this table will expand rapidly.

It consists of 15 or so columns ranging from tiny and medium ints to 30 character varchars.

There is no ID field - I can join 6 columns to form a primary key - this would be a var char total length about 45.

When it's imported I need to report on this data through a web front end at summary levels so I see myself having to build reporting tables from this after importing.

Within this data are many fields that repeat themselves in each days import - date, region, customer etc, only half the columns each day are specific to the record.

Questions:

1. Should I import it all into one table immediately as a dump table.
2. Should I transform the data through the import process and split the import across different tables
3. Should I form an id field based on the columns I can to get a unique key during the import
4. Should I use auto inc id field for this.
5. What sort of table should this be InnoDB etc

My fear is data overload on this table which will make extracting to reporting tables harder and harder as it builds?

Advice really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Having autoinc id is usually more helpful than not having it
2. To ensure data integrity you can have uniq index on your 6 columns that make up ID
3. MySQL is pretty comfortable with millions of records in database if you have enough RAM
4. If you still have a fear of millions of records - just aggregate your data on monthly basis into another table. If you can't - add more RAM.
5. Transform as much of your data during importing as possible as long as it doesn't hurt performance. Transforming the data when it's already imported adds unnecessary load to MySQL server and if you can avoid doing so - avoid.
6. MyISAM is(was?) usually better for statistical kind of data, kind that doesn't get UPDATEd too often but InnoDB has caught up in past few years(have a look at percona's XtraDB engine) and is basically same performance-wise.

I think the most important point here is to define your data retention rates - it's rare that you have to retain daily resolution after a year or two.

Aggregate into lower resolution frames and archive(mysqldump > bzip is quite efficient) if you think you might still need daily resolution in future.

Comment: thanks - good points - i think i'm going to find it hard to add ids during the import that's the main problem. I can't see how I can break up the csv data logically and be able to use the generated id's as foreign keys in tables i am also adding to in the transformation process.
I think you are righ ton the archiving thing for sure.